# Apple Script to change all the events in iCal's end date to one specific date

Tags: macos, applescript

I am new to Mac. I have some 50 recurring events where the end date is not specified.
I am planning to change all the recurring events to a specific end date. I am looking for an apple script to change it in one run. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The following script should do what you need.  You will need to change the title to the name of the calendar you are interested from "Home".  And you will need to change the end date from "20130902" to whatever you need (in YYYYMMDD format).

For whatever reason, iCal seems to subtract 1 day from this end date, so in this example, the end dates will all be set to 1st Sept 2013.

```
tell application "Calendar"
  repeat with thisCal in (calendars whose title is "Home")
    setEndDate of me to "20130902" for thisCal
  end repeat
end tell

on setEndDate to endDate for thisCalendar
  tell application "Calendar"
    repeat with thisEvent in (events of thisCalendar)
      if recurrence of thisEvent is not missing value and recurrence of thisEvent does not contain "UNTIL" then
        set recurrence of thisEvent to recurrence of thisEvent & ";UNTIL=" & endDate
      end if
    end repeat
  end tell
end setEndDate
```